# I'm getting an error when installing brms R package

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm trying to install "brms" package but keep getting an error.
First, I installed "brms" package, and then call the package from the library.
I'm getting the following error message. "Error in library(brms) : there is no package called ‘brms’
Can someone help me?

```
install.packages("brms")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/.......’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is
  later:
     binary source needs_compilation
brms 2.17.0 2.18.0             FALSE

installing the source package ‘brms’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/brms_2.18.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4486548 bytes (4.3 MB)
downloaded 4.3 MB

* installing *source* package 'brms' ...
** package 'brms' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
Warning: namespace 'brms' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object 'brmsfit_example1'
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning message:
package 'Rcpp' was built under R version 4.0.5 
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'Brobdingnag'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'brms'
* removing 'C:/Users/....'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\....\downloaded_packages’

library(brms)
```

> Error in library(brms) : there is no package called ‘brms’

Comment: The installation probably failed and you overlooked the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Note in the warning :
`installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status` means that the installation failed.

and `there is no package called 'Brobdingnag'` means that this dependency is missing
see `?install.packages`
you can use the argument `dependencies = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you probably didn't let the 'install' step finish. That package has a lot of dependencies. Try `install.packages("brms")` function again and wait for it to finish.

Comment: It seems that I'm getting some kind of errors when installing 'brms' package but not sure what they are and how to fix it.

Comment: What’s it say? Does it just not load? Try updating R to the newest version first